# SSIS-SQL Deployment

Tags: sql-server, ssis, integration, etl

I have a SSIS package. It contains some `tasks` that include *Turkish characters*, also in the `Data Flow` Task some SQL queries include Turkish characters in where clause.

When I execute the package manually on **Visual Studio**, it works fine but after deployment to **SQL Server** and run it via job, it works wrongly. Probably it deploys SQL server with *Turkish characters* corruption.

What can I do? Please help me.

Best regards.

Comment: Would a reproduction be something like `SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeTable WHERE User = N'Hüseyin Çırak'` That works in Visual Studio but then fails when run on the server?

Comment: It did not work. In Visual Studio it works fine but not on the server.